# Basic Java MVC: Beans and associative entities with attributes

Tags: java, javabeans, entity-relationship

I'm working in this movie db project for college where I need to create a website based on java to do advanced searches in a huge postgresql database. I'm not using hibernate or similar tools. Here's part of the ER diagram for the database:
[image]

As you can see, the associative entity actormovie links the entities actor and movie while also listing the character portrayed. I have created two simple beans, Actor and Movie, with attributes, getters and setters.

This is my first java web project with focus on MVC, so I'm more than a little lost. My question is: Should I create a bean mapping the associative table? If not, what do I do with the as_character attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.
This is because the relation Actor->Movie has a property `as_character`, you can also find a way to not do a class, but in the long time it will cause problems (maybe some stupid bug created because you forgot it, or someone else didn't know it, something you don't want to deal with).
If this is your first approach I think what can make you confused is how to represents the relationship.
The first approach that come in mind, most of the time, is to have an ActorMovie class like:

```
public class ActorMovie {
    Integer actor_id;
    Integer movieid;
    String as_character;

    //getters, setters, equals, hashCode, toString
}
```

But you can also think at it as a **value** of `Actor` (or `Movie`) and have it like:

```
public class ActorMovie {
    Integer movieid;
    String as_character;

    //getters, setters, equals, hashCode, toString
}
```

and a `Actor` class:

```
public class Actor {
    Integer actor_id;
    String name;
    String sex;
    Set<ActorMovie> movies;

    //getters, setters, equals, hashCode, toString
}
```

Both of them solve the problems, they just change how you will interact with these data through the code, to learn when is better to use one or the other you have to try both and see what change, so choose what you feel more "natural" and see the results.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Would it be wrong somehow to have something like this instead of referencing ids?

`public class ActorMovie {
    Actor actor;
    Movie movie;
    String as_character;

    //getters, setters, equals, hashCode, toString
}`

Comment: Well, I like it either way. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it can be a solution too! What change if you use a `Movie` is that whoever has access to an `ActorMovie` can call the setters of the movie, so maybe you load an `ActorMovie`, then you can do something like `actorMovie.getMovie().setName("something else")`. You need to take it account into when choosing what use (for a better explanation do some search about the aggregate design pattern)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need. The class Actor will have a list of Movie, and the Movie class, a list of Actor. Just map like this.

To the character attribute, you could create a map in the Actor class, where the key, is the movie, and the value, the character (Or a list of character, because an actor can have many characters in the same movie):

`Map<Movie, List<String>> characters = new HashMap<>()`

Comment: What about the "as_character" attribute?

Comment: That's an elegant solution, I just think it'll be harder to work with than the one I accepted since I'll constantly deal with data from both entities. Thanks for the reply tho, I definitely learned a thing or two looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how your project will develop. You should create bean mapping for the associative table, if you are not using Object Relational Mapping(as you stated in the question). If you will introduce Object Relational Mapping later on, then Actor can own as_character property, then you should not create bean mapping for the associative table .